# Remove a column from a CSV

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have a csv file which is in a form of

```
input.csv

1,AREA,"POLYGON((103.855 1.27267,103.856 1.27316,103.851 1.27506,103.853 1.27941,103.853 1.2793,103.852 1.27879,103.852 1.27639,103.851 1.27624,103.851 1.27634,103.851 1.27661,103.851 1.27699,103.852 1.27985,103.852 1.28138,103.853 1.28188,103.853 1.28189,103.853 1.28058,103.853 1.28044,103.853 1.28048,103.853 1.28084,103.853 1.28206,103.853 1.28216,103.853 1.28205,103.853 1.28205,103.854 1.28196,103.854 1.28209,103.855 1.28141,103.855 1.2813,103.855 1.28086,103.856 1.28001,103.859 1.28528,103.859 1.28555,103.859 1.28556,103.859 1.28586,103.859 1.28587,103.859 1.28629,103.859 1.28662,103.859 1.28669,103.87 1.28157,103.873 1.27787,103.871 1.27586,103.863 1.26996,103.862 1.26924,103.861 1.2689,103.86 1.26869,103.859 1.26884,103.858 1.26921,103.856 1.2702,103.855 1.27088,103.856 1.27227,103.855 1.27253,103.851 1.27428,103.852 1.2739,103.855 1.27267))"
```

I want to remove the third column which is not fixed in size. I tried with the

```
cut -d, -f3 --complement input.csv
```

But it is not working fine.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the first two fields are simple -- never containing quotes commas -- then `cut -d, -f1-2` would do it

Answer (score 4):

The `cut` tool is not smart enough to figure out that those commas in the third column are not delimiters.

You can however select a range of columns: in this case `-f1-2` will select columns 1 through 2, thereby excluding 3.

However for general CSV processing you need a more powerful parser, such as those found in scripting languages like Python and Perl.

Comment: Yes cut -d, -f1-2 works perfectly